# How can I interleave two lists in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

In one place in a makfile I need

a.ml a.mli b.ml b.mli c.ml c.mli etc.

I another place, I need

a.mli b.mli c.mli etc.

Without duplication, can I define two separate, equal length lists (one of the .ml files and one of the .mli files), and then define another list to be the interleaving of the two lists?

In fact, since there is always a .ml and a corresponding .mli, can I generate all this from just a list of filenames with no extensions (i.e a b c etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. This is probably the most general:

```
LIST := a b c

MLLIST := $(addsuffix .ml,$(LIST))
MLILIST := $(addsuffix .mli,$(LIST))

both = $(1).ml $(1).mli

BOTHLIST := $(foreach x,$(LIST),$(call both,$(x)))
```

Comment: This worked fine, although I had to write

BOTHLIST = $(foreach x,$(LIST),$(call both,$(x)))

Answer (score 1):

If you get a copy of the Make Standard Library: http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/ you can use the `pairmap` function, which I believe does what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I've used the lighter weight suggestion.

Comment: Yes, Beta's answer works very well for this situation where you have a known relationship between the two lists you want to interleave (they have the same prefix).  If you have two random lists that have no such relationship, that solution won't work.

Comment: Agreed. My answer suited the content of the question, but not its title. I considered adding a general list-interleavener, but it's a horrible hack because of some glaring omissions in Make's list manipulation functions. (The list `1 2 3...` is very useful, but even generating *that* is a pain.)

Comment: _it's a horrible hack because of some glaring omissions in Make's list manipulation functions_  Yes, that's why the GMSL is such an incredible achievement :-).